# Android BLE - Reading Characaricts

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.3-jelly-bean

My building a BLE ap that connects to a cutsom hardware.
I'm using Samsung Galaxy S3,Android version 4.3 for testings.
I've successfully connected to the remote device, and was able to list all the device's services.
The problem is that I can't seem to read any of the service's Characaricts.
Here's the code for the displayGattServices function(taken directly from Google's sample code) -

```
// Demonstrates how to iterate through the supported GATT Services/Characteristics.
// In this sample, we populate the data structure that is bound to the ExpandableListView
// on the UI.
private void displayGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
    if (gattServices == null) return;
    String uuid = null;
    String unknownServiceString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_service);
    String unknownCharaString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_characteristic);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattServiceData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> gattCharacteristicData
            = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
    mGattCharacteristics = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();

    // Loops through available GATT Services.
    for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
        HashMap<String, String> currentServiceData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        uuid = gattService.getUuid().toString();
        currentServiceData.put(
                LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownServiceString));
        currentServiceData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
        gattServiceData.add(currentServiceData);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattCharacteristicGroupData =
                new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics =
                gattService.getCharacteristics();
        ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charas =
                new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();

        // Loops through available Characteristics.
 for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
            charas.add(gattCharacteristic);
            HashMap<String, String> currentCharaData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
            currentCharaData.put(
                    LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownCharaString));
            currentCharaData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
            gattCharacteristicGroupData.add(currentCharaData);
        }
        mGattCharacteristics.add(charas);
        gattCharacteristicData.add(gattCharacteristicGroupData);
    }

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter gattServiceAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            gattServiceData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] {LIST_NAME, LIST_UUID},
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
            gattCharacteristicData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] {LIST_NAME, LIST_UUID},
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
    );
    mGattServicesList.setAdapter(gattServiceAdapter);
}
```

This is the service code -

```
   private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                             final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    // This is special handling for the Heart Rate Measurement profile.  Data parsing is
    // carried out as per profile specifications:
    // http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml
    if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
        int format = -1;
        if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
        } else {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
        }
        final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received heart rate: %d", heartRate));
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, String.valueOf(heartRate));
    } else {
        // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
        final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
            for(byte byteChar : data)
                stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}


    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
    }
};
```

Whenever I try to retrieve Characaricts, gattService.getCharacteristics() returns an empty list.
Am I doing it right, and the problem is with the hardware, or am I missing Something?

Thanks

Comment: The types of operations usually deliver their results by invoking callback methods you must define - at least that's how I've managed to read characteristics from a BTLE device.  Without looking into the details of the methods you are trying to call, my suspicion is that you could be going about this in a mistaken way, and perhaps confusing some other capability for some other purpose for that which you desire.

Comment: I've added the code of the Service, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever I try to retrieve Characaricts, gattService.getCharacteristics() returns an empty list.

You received the empty list since The remote device which support BLE chip not support any Characteristics.

> the problem is hardware

This is not problem with the Galaxy S3 device, actually problem be at remote device which support BLE chip (firmware side), like Galaxy Gear ... If Galaxy Gear device not support any Characteristics, your Galaxy S3 will not find out any Characteristics.

*p/s : Your coding get from Sample Code is good. Works for me.*

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct.

There are two possible reasons, why you can not see characteristics:

1) hardware does not support any characteristics. The best way to test this, is may be to install some scan application that allows you to explore BLE device. (there are many availble for Andorid, e.g. SensorTag, that can also scan other devices) or even better some for iOS, where BLE stack is more stable.

2) Andorid BLE stack is not fully stable (as discussed in many thread here)- you did something, that crashed it it internally, and the way out is to try disable and enable BT or, if this does not help, restart device. But in this case, this is not probable, since you can see services.